# RewriteRule regex to extract part of a string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some issues with the following task:

Redirect from:

```
example.com/catalog/index.php/cPath/24?osCsid=gvil7l7h2vu910f787248i14j4
```

To:

```
example.com/mysitenew/index.php?dest=products&cat=24
```

The trick is to take the number after `cPath/` and strip out the `?` and everything after it.

I have tried back and forth with regex in `RewriteRule` but I am not an expert and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^catalog/index\.php/cPath/([^/]+)/?$ /mysitenew/index.php?dest=products&cat=$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Works beautifully, would it be possible to explain the regex to my newbie self?

Comment: Yes sure. This rule captures part of URL after `/catalog/index.php/cPath/` into `$1` (captured group). Then in the target URI it redirects it to `/mysitenew/index.php?dest=products&cat=$1`. Also original query string is automatically discarded whenever new query parameter is added.